# Multiplicity constraint violated. The role "....' of the relationship '...' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

again i am stucked with un-clrear error raised by EF. I have the following model class:-

```
public partial class TMSServer
    {
        public TMSServer()
        {
            this.TMSServers1 = new HashSet<TMSServer>();
            this.TMSVirtualMachines = new HashSet<TMSVirtualMachine>();
        }

        public int TMSServerID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ServerModelID { get; set; }
        public int DataCenterID { get; set; }
        public string ILOIP { get; set; }
        public int RackID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StatusID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BackUpStatusID { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OperatingSystemID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VirtualCenterID { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }
        public long IT360SiteID { get; set; }

        public virtual DataCenter DataCenter { get; set; }
        public virtual OperatingSystem OperatingSystem { get; set; }
        public virtual ServerModel ServerModel { get; set; }
        public virtual Technology Technology { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologyBackUpStatu TechnologyBackUpStatu { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologyRole TechnologyRole { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologyStatu TechnologyStatu { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSRack TMSRack { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TMSServer> TMSServers1 { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSServer TMSServer1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TMSVirtualMachine> TMSVirtualMachines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the following post create action method:-

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ServerJoin sj, FormCollection formValues)
        {
            string controllername = RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
//code goes here

                        repository.InsertOrUpdateServer(sj.Server, User.Identity.Name, assetid);
                        repository.Save()
```

and the following Repository method:-

```
public void InsertOrUpdateServer(TMSServer server, string username,long assetid)
        {
            var resource = GetResourceDetials(assetid);
            if (server.TMSServerID == default(int))
            {
                // New entity
               int technologyypeID = GetTechnologyTypeID("Server");
                Technology technology = new Technology
                {
                    IsDeleted = true,
                    TypeID = technologyypeID,
                    Tag = "S" + GetTagMaximumeNumber(technologyypeID).ToString(),
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                    IT360ID = assetid

                };

                InsertOrUpdateTechnology(technology);
                Save();



                var auditinfo = IntiateTechnologyAudit(tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "ADD").ID,
                tms.TechnologyTypes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "Server").AssetTypeID,
                username, technology.TechnologyID);

                server.TMSServerID= technology.TechnologyID;
                server.IT360SiteID = resource.SITEID.Value;
                              tms.TMSServers.Add(server);
                               technology.IsDeleted = false;
                InsertOrUpdateTechnology(technology);
                InsertOrUpdateTechnologyAudit(auditinfo);
            }

        }
```

;

But when i try to call the Post Create action method i will get the following exception:-

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079   Message=Multiplicity constraint violated. The
>   role 'TMSServers' of the relationship 'TMSModel.FK_Servers_Technology'
>   has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.   Source=System.Data.Entity   StackTrace:

The Technology model class which is envlved in the exception looks as follow:-

```
public partial class Technology
    {
        public Technology()
        {
            this.TMSSwitchPorts = new HashSet<TMSSwitchPort>();
            this.TechnologyAudits = new HashSet<TechnologyAudit>();
            this.TechnologyIPs = new HashSet<TechnologyIP>();
        }

        public int TechnologyID { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TypeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> IT360ID { get; set; }

        public virtual TMSFirewall TMSFirewall { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSRack TMSRack { get; set; }
        public virtual TMsRouter TMsRouter { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSServer TMSServer { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSStorageDevice TMSStorageDevice { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSSwitch TMSSwitch { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TMSSwitchPort> TMSSwitchPorts { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologyType TechnologyType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TechnologyAudit> TechnologyAudits { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TechnologyIP> TechnologyIPs { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSVirtualMachine TMSVirtualMachine { get; set; }
    }
```